# Is there any database model having these "no-sql", "schema free" & "relational" ? is it support c++?

Tags: database, mongodb, database-design, nosql, faunadb

I need schema free db with relational features for my C++ application.

I already using PostgreSQL and Mysql in my project.

I want to store data relationally in document and need CRUD using SQL.

Comment: "NoSQL" implies not relational. What does "schema free db with relational features" possibly mean? Or "store data relationally in document"? Or "need CRUD"? This is not clear. Use enough words, sentences & references to parts of examples to clearly & fully say what you mean.

Comment: Your own link shows a diagram where "Relational" *does not intersect* "NoSQL". Also it also contradicts that via "Relational NoSQL: Yes". (But the the NoSQL movement doesn't understand SQL poorly embodies the relational model & that a specialized DB can still have a relational interface, so can still be a relational DBMS--"relational" means presenting data as relations.)

Comment: The question is unclear but you can store and query "free-form" JSON documents in Postgresql. Also, why do you use *both* Postgresql and Mysql at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

"Relational" and "schema-free" are mutually exclusive.

Comment: Plz check [FaunaDB](https://fauna.com/blog/relational-nosql-is-an-option), what I want it have except it doesn't support c++. [Erwin Smout](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1388192/erwin-smout)

Comment: @MayankWasekar No, you edit what is relevant into your post to clearly ask a question.

Comment: You have not provided any details/specifics re. "what you want".

Answer (score 0):

Modern DBMS support several data models. For example, SQL Server supports relational, document-oriented (both XML and JSON) and graph (network) data models. You can combine the use of different models in the same database. A typical example, the table of documents contains several columns corresponding to most important attributes including the keys, and one column that stores an XML.

However, the relational data model is well structured by default, so it's hard to implement a schemaless relational database. This may be simulated with Excel sheets or tables using only some "variant" data type but such a solution seems to be fragile and has performance issues.

Another way is to use EAV extension inside a relational database.

You can have a look on "[Programming with databases](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/2956300806)" book containing some examples of use Yes/NoSQL.

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at AgensGraph database. AgensGraph is the only true multi model database supporting Relational Database and Graph Database(Schema Free). It is as well supporting Key-Value and document model. Also its based on C language.

[AgensGraph](http://%20%20https://bitnine.net/agensgraph/)

Answer (score 0):

The actual answer to your specific question based on your parameters:

1. Schema free
2. CRUD support
3. SQL "like", aka Relational
4. [C++ support](https://www.arangodb.com/2017/11/introduction-fuerte-arangodb-c-plus-plus-driver/)

is [ArangoDB](https://www.arangodb.com/why-arangodb/).